# how to install python package in Raspbian?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspbian, pycrypto

I'm trying to install pycrypto for python 3.x.x on raspberry pi
but when i run `python setup.py install`
from the command line, it is by default installed to python 2.7.x
i have installed `python-dev` and still with no luck, i have read that using a PIP might help, but unfortunately i don't know how to use it. all my codes are written for python 3.3.x  and it would take me a very long time to re-write them all for 2.7.
so how can i fix it without re-writing my codes

Answer (score 0):

Having looked into it there does not seem to be a pycrypto version for python3 at the moment. I think you're options are to look for an alternative package or to convert your code to python 2. There are tools available which can do this automatically, for example 3to2 is available in pip.

Comment: What exactly do you find buggy about pip?

Comment: @stmfunk using `pip3 install pycrpto` yeilds an error message `-bash: pip3: command not found`  i don't quiet understand your answer, i have downloaded pycrypto package on the raspberry, the package is .tar.gz  setup.py is availible once the package is unpacked, so how exactly can i use it, and if you dont recommend `PIP` than what other option suggest

Comment: I made some changes to the answer